# Nothing on screen while booting

Tags: boot, hardware, sd-card, hdmi, boot-issues

I am having trouble booting my raspberry pi 0 w. I am using a 32 gb micro sd card with noobs downloaded on it. I have followed the steps on the raspberry pi website to boot the pi, but when I plug in the power source nothing appears on screen. The green led turns on which is good because according to my research that should mean that the pi is reading the card. In the past I was able to boot the pi with my 16 gb sd card, but that has since been corrupted. How do I fix my problem and make have the screen show signs of the pi booting?

Comment: What is the class of your card? For information regarding the class of your card, read the section "What speed can I expect from my SD card" from this article: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/sd-card-speed-test/ .  You can also check the compatibility of your card on this list: https://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards  Please let us know. Thanks.

Comment: You could drop Noobs and just image Raspbian Lite as a test.  Unless you gave a specific need for Noobs I would move away from it ASAP as it can give lots of issues.  I would also use Etcher to create the card as it does not need the files unzipping and it will run a verification pass after creating the image.